# Java – How do I use counter data for analytics?

Tags: java, jframe, counter

I have a JFrame with three tabs: Home, Statistics, and About.

On the Home tab, I have a counter that tracks how many times you click your left or right arrow, and it updates a counter (I use the `KeyListener` method):

[image]

On the Statistics tab, I want to somehow import these Left and Right values that I generate from the counter.

[image]

But, I don't know how to. Can someone help me out here?

Edit:
Here is the code for the Home tab (Left/Right counter)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class HomePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    // Variables
    private int counter = 0;
    private int counter2 = 0;
    private JLabel counterLabel;
    private JLabel counterLabel2;
    private JButton countUpButton;
    private JButton countDownButton;

    // Panel Elements
    public HomePanel() {

        countUpButton = new JButton ("Left");
        countUpButton.setBounds(195, 121, 75, 29);
        countUpButton.addKeyListener(this);

        countDownButton = new JButton ("Right");
        countDownButton.setBounds(195, 162, 77, 29);
        countDownButton.addKeyListener(this);

        counterLabel = new JLabel("" + counter);
        counterLabel.setBounds(282, 126, 34, 16);
        counterLabel2 = new JLabel("" + counter2);
        counterLabel2.setBounds(282, 167, 34, 16);
        setLayout(null);

        add (countUpButton);
        add (counterLabel);
        add (countDownButton);
        add (counterLabel2);
    }

    // Key Listener
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // Ensures counter updates once per stroke
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            counter++;
            counterLabel.setText("" + counter);
        } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            counter2++;
            counterLabel2.setText("" + counter2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

And here is the code for the Statistics tab:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;


public class StatsPanel extends JPanel {

    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    private JTextField textField_5;
    private JTextField textField_6;
    public StatsPanel() {
        setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(41, 43, 371, 234);
        add(panel);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("LEFT:");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(115, 39, 33, 16);
        panel.add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lblRight = new JLabel("RIGHT:");
        lblRight.setBounds(105, 67, 43, 16);
        panel.add(lblRight);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("TOTAL:");
        lblNewLabel_2.setBounds(102, 95, 46, 16);
        panel.add(lblNewLabel_2);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_3 = new JLabel("% LEFT:");
        lblNewLabel_3.setBounds(102, 123, 46, 16);
        panel.add(lblNewLabel_3);

        JLabel lblNewLabel_4 = new JLabel("% RIGHT: ");
        lblNewLabel_4.setBounds(91, 151, 60, 16);
        panel.add(lblNewLabel_4);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setBounds(160, 33, 134, 28);
        panel.add(textField_2);
        textField_2.setColumns(10);

        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setBounds(160, 61, 134, 28);
        panel.add(textField_3);
        textField_3.setColumns(10);

        textField_4 = new JTextField();
        textField_4.setBounds(160, 89, 134, 28);
        panel.add(textField_4);
        textField_4.setColumns(10);

        textField_5 = new JTextField();
        textField_5.setBounds(160, 117, 134, 28);
        panel.add(textField_5);
        textField_5.setColumns(10);

        textField_6 = new JTextField();
        textField_6.setBounds(160, 145, 134, 28);
        panel.add(textField_6);
        textField_6.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");
        btnCalculate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                // Variables
                double num1, num2, ans, percEq1, percEq2, percLeft, percRight;

                try {

                    num1 = Double.parseDouble(textField_2.getText());
                    num2 = Double.parseDouble(textField_3.getText());

                    ans = num1 + num2;
                    textField_4.setText(Double.toString(ans));

                    percEq1 = (num1/(num1+num2))*100;
                    percLeft = Math.round(percEq1);
                    textField_5.setText(Double.toString(percLeft));

                    percEq2 = (num2/(num1+num2))*100;
                    percRight = Math.round(percEq2);
                    textField_6.setText(Double.toString(percRight));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid number!");
                }

            }
        });
        btnCalculate.setBounds(79, 185, 117, 29);
        panel.add(btnCalculate);

        JButton btnRest = new JButton("Reset");
        btnRest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                textField_2.setText("");
                textField_3.setText("");
                textField_4.setText("");
                textField_5.setText("");
                textField_6.setText("");
            }
        });


        btnRest.setBounds(197, 185, 117, 29);
        panel.add(btnRest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using variables in the parent container so every tab can access them or, from the statistics tab, ask the values to the parent frame and the parent asks to the home tab.
It's not a short code and you haven't attached yours, so I hope your get the idea.

In the main container you have something like this:

```
KeyPressStats statistics = new KeyPressStats();
HomePanel home = new HomePanel(statistics);
StatsPanel stats = new StatsPanel(statistics);
JTabbedPane tabbed = new JTabbedPane();
tabbed.addTab("Home", home);
tabbed.addTab("Stats", stats);
tabbed.setVisible(true);
```

KeyPressStats is as follows:

```
public class KeyPressStats {
  private int leftCount = 0;
  private int rightCount = 0;

  public int getLeftCount() {
    return leftCount;
  }

  public void setLeftCount(int leftCount) {
    this.leftCount = leftCount;
  }

  public int getRightCount() {
    return rightCount;
  }

  public void setRightCount(int rightCount) {
    this.rightCount = rightCount;
  }

  public void incrementRight() {
    rightCount++;
  }

  public void incrementLeft() {
    leftCount++;
  }

}
```

And the code in the Home and stats tabs will have these changes:

```
public class HomePanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
  ...
  private KeyPressStats stats;

  public HomePanel(KeyPressStats stats) {
    this.stats = stats;
    countUpButton = new JButton("Left");
    countUpButton.setBounds(195, 121, 75, 29);
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {    
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
      stats.incrementLeft();
      counterLabel.setText("" + stats.getLeftCount());
    } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
      stats.incrementRight();
      counterLabel2.setText("" + stats.getRightCount());
    }
  }


public class StatsPanel extends JPanel {
...
  public StatsPanel(KeyPressStats stats) {
    ...
    textField_2 = new JTextField(""+stats.getLeftCount());
    textField_2.setBounds(160, 33, 134, 28);
    ...
    textField_3 = new JTextField(""+stats.getRightCount());
    textField_3.setBounds(160, 61, 134, 28);
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. I posted my code. Can you help me out? I'm still a little confused on which variables to use and how to use them.

Comment: The easiest is to create an object, lets call it KeyPressedStatistics, in the JFrame. That object will have the counter for left and the counter for right. You need to send that object as parameter to the constructor of Home and Statistics. (You forget to attach the game) and in the home, in the key pressed event you increase the counters of that object. And in the statistics panel you just need to poll  the values from the object that you received in the constructor. I'm sorry for not attaching code, I'm writing from my phone. If you still have dubts I'll check them when I get home.

Comment: If you could post some sample code, that would be great!

Comment: I added some code. I suggest to study about best coding practices and follow tutorias. Regards.